# HTML/CSS how can I keep right hand div responsive while specifying width

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a webpage with a left and float right div, which is supposed to be responsive.  I want the righthand div to slide under the left hand div if the screen is narrow. I have that sort of working, but a problem remains.

Both divs have images inside them, and the images seem to be causing the div width to increase, which in turn puts everything in the wrong place.  But if I specify any kind of width at all (width in %, width in px, max-width, etc) on the right hand div, it won't slide under when the screen narrows.

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

and here is how it looks sliding under:

[image]

What you can see for both divs is that the width far exceed the size of the images, and that is a problem in the right hand image.  (The small black and green boxes in the right hand div are outlines of the `<a` tags.)

The code:

```
<!---white body --->
<div style = "width:75%; margin:auto;background-color:white; border:2px solid black">

<div class="container">
  <div class="one">
     <a href = 'ind-pg1.cfm'  >
     <img src = "ind-leopard-happy.jpeg" alt = "eznplogo" 
          style = "width:50%; height:auto "></a>
   </div>


 <div class="two">
    <div style = 'width:50%; float:right'> 
      <a href = 'dashboard.cfm' style = 'border:2px solid black; '>
          <img src = 'ind-pict-login.png' style = "width:30% "></a> 
      <a href = 'ind-purchase.cfm' style = 'border:2px solid green'>
          <img src = 'ind-pict-signup.png'style = "width:30%"></a> 
    </div> 
 </div>
 </div><!---container--->   
 </div><!---white body --->
```

The css:

```
.container {
overflow:hidden;
height: 500px;
}

.one {
position: relative;
float:left;    
background-color: lightblue;   
width:40%;
}

.two {   
background-color: yellow;    
float:right;
}
```

First, I don't understand why the divs are wider than the images; and why they don't get narrower when I narrow the image.  If there is some way to make the right hand div narrower without setting a width for it, I'd like to be able to do that. EDIT:  IT TURNS OUT THE WIDTH OF THE DIV IS DETERMINED BY THE ORIGINAL SIZE OF THE IMAGE.  BY SCALING DOWN THE IMAGE I WAS ABLE TO CONTROL THE WIDTH OF THE DIV.

However, I also don't understand why setting a width on the right hand div is causing it to stop sliding under.

If anyone can explain either thing to me that would be very helpful.  Can anyone suggest the way to do this so that it works without excessively wide divs?

Comment: A couple of suggestions, and this may or may not fix your issue. It would be a good idea to include a https://jsfiddle.net/ w/ your post, so that we may better help. Your `.container` element needs to have a `clear:both;` applied. You always do this when you have elements that are children w/ `float` applied. Next, you need to define `media queries`, which states, "when the viewport is YYpx, then use these styles (as opposed to desktop)". Now, perhaps it goes down to a new line b/c there's no `border-box` set, or your images are not responsive. Again, a jsfiddle will help

Comment: Also it's confusing to have inline styles and other styles in a CSS file. Proper coding would be to never have inline styles on elements. It's best to start w/ setting your images as responsive, and to move the `width` off the images and set it to the parent element, which would be the `a`. The .img-responsive class applies `max-width: 100%, height: auto, and display:block` to the image.

Comment: Your comments are most helpful, about the container, @media, border-box.  Re the styles, I was working on the program and changing things on the fly.  I always move the inline styles to a CSS file when I'm finished.